address of static variable as constexpr
I understand why this does not compile:
int main() {
    constexpr int i = 0;
    constexpr const int* ptr = &i;
}

local var address is evaluated in runtime (although could be resolved in this example).
This compiles:
constexpr int i = 0;
int main() {
    constexpr const int* r = &i;
}

And also this compiles:
int main() {
    static constexpr int i = 0;
    constexpr const int* r = &i;
}

To my understanding, this means that resolving the addresses of static variables are considered a compile-time feature. Is this behavior mandatory by the specification?

The constexpr specifier declares that it is possible to evaluate the value of the function or variable at compile time, which is valid of i in all cases. But same cannot be for r when i is local variable then &i is not available at compile time.

The first program will be valid in C++26.

@BrianBi By what change? The current draft seems to still forbid this in https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#15.3.

The second and third programs are valid standard C++. It is not only a specific compiler allowing it. Any conforming compiler must compile this.
The result of a constant expression can be or contain pointers to objects with static storage duration.
But that importantly does not mean that the addresses of these objects as their numeric values can be used at compile-time. The only way it would be possible to obtain these numerical values would be with reinterpret_cast which is forbidden at compile-time.
So the compiler only has to track what static storage duration objects exist and whether a given constant expression result points to any of these objects symbolically without needing to bother about address values. Actual values for the addresses can be filled in later by the linker as usual.
